# read multiple sheets from excel in a one shot in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to read multiple sheets from a single excel file  in a single shot in matlab?

I have a 80 sheets in a excel file, to read these sheets I have to execute xlsread commands eighty times. Its take too much time.

Is there any alternative wey to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22365-function-for-faster-data-transfer-matlab-%3C-%3E-excel)?

Comment: Mentioning your previous attempts is very important in questions on SO. How long does the execution take with `xlsread1` as compared with `xlsread`? How fast do you expect this to go? Also, just wondering - is the source `.xls` or `.xlsx`?

Comment: It would be much easier if you use `actxserver`. Read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293325), it doesn't directly answer your question though it is related.

Comment: thanx to all. solve the problem